# Why I can not receive data from jQuery (PHP)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, get

I have a PHP form:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="CheckBoxForm">
    foreach ( $results as $result ) :
      <input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="check_list[]" value="'.($result->meta_value).'"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

I take values from it in js file:

```
        jQuery('#CheckBoxForm').on('submit', function(e) {

            var chkArray = [];
            var CheckBoxForm=jQuery(this).serialize();
            alert(CheckBoxForm);

            jQuery(".chk:checked").each(function() {
            chkArray.push($(this).val());
            });

            var selected;
            selected = chkArray.join(',') + ",";

            jQuery.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data: selected,     
            success:function(data){
            jQuery("#feedback_country").html(data);
            }
            });

            return false;    

    });

});
```

If I alert *selected* it gives me list of values. So script has initialized and took data.

At the end of the script it receive feedback data *html(data)*  and send it back to initial php file.

**PHP file which take request from js file (POST REQUEST)** has such code:

```
foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected){
echo $selected."</br>";
}
```

And **it send back 0.** I can't understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too much extra code in your JavaScript that is unneeded.  You don't need those `chkArray` or `selected` variables.

```
jQuery('#CheckBoxForm').on('submit', function(e) {
    var CheckBoxForm = jQuery(this).serialize();

    jQuery.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: CheckBoxForm,     
        success:function(data){
            jQuery("#feedback_country").html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

That should be all you need.  `serialize()` will take all the values from the form and create a string in the correct format to be sent to your PHP script.

Note: Your HTML is incorrect, your form should look like this:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="CheckBoxForm">
    <?php foreach($results as $result): ?>
        <input type="checkbox" class="chk" name="check_list[]" value="<?=$result->meta_value?>"/>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

You want to use the `name` attribute, not `id` on your checkboxes.

Comment: Rocket, thank you so much. It works now. Good luck to you and all the best from my side!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are sending a single string instead of key - value pairs:

```
selected = chkArray.join(',') + ",";
...

  data: selected,
```

Although I would not recommend building the query string manually - `serialize()` will take care of the correct escaping - you can send your check-list string like:

```
data: {check_list: selected},
```

**Edit:** Now in php you will have a `$_POST['check_list']` variable but that is a list in a comma-separated string. So to convert it into an array and loop over it, you would need something like:

```
$arr = explode(',', $_POST['check_list']);
foreach ($arr as $selected) {
  echo $selected."</br>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Jeroen for your response. I have made this changed and it still send me 0 back. :(

Comment: @inno.vlad Check my update, you need to change the php-side as well.

Comment: hm.. strange. still 0 at response. what can I do for debug where the problem is? cause there are no errors in the console.

Comment: @inno.vlad Dump your variables, `console.log()` for the javascript ones and `var_dump()` for the php ones. They should all pop-up in the console, either directly or in the ajax response.

Comment: Jeroen, Thank you for your support. I have tried Rocket's modification and it works for me, so I keep it. Good luck to you in all of your projects.